# How to check if code is run locally or on a cluster in Python

Tags: python, cluster-computing

I have a python script that will be run both, on a local machine as well as on a computing cluster. I am looking for an efficient way for the script to check, whether it is run locally or not. What would be the best solution to that?
I thought about passing some hardware information along and checking if it has changed, but surely there must be a more elegant solution than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the hostname of the machine it's running on with the `os` module

```
 import os
 os.system('hostname')
```

this will output the hostname to console.

If you want to capture the output use `.popen` like so:

```
 a=os.popen('hostname').read()
```

this will return a string, which you may have to encode into `utf-8` to make it readable like so:

```
 print(a.encode('utf-8'))
```

But this last bit really only applies if your os language has special characters

Answer (score 3):

For config like this you could set an environment variable on the cluster / your local machine and then have the script check for that variable to determine where it is:

```
import os

where_am_i = os.getenv('WHEREAMI')


if where_am_i == 'cluster':
    # Do the cluster stuff
else:
    # Do the local machine stuff
```